# Deploying Typescript + Angular app to Azure App Service via Azure Devops pipeline (ng modue not found)

Tags: azure, azure-web-apps, devops, azure-devops, angular

Got this typescript + angular app that works great locally.

Trying to set up a deployment pipeline on Azure Devops that builds and releases to App Service (linux nodejs webapp).

The plumbing works, the whole pipeline succeeds - both the build and release stages.

However, I cannot get the deployed app to work - it has a 'ng module not found' error when it attempts 'npm start'. And that's that.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix?

Here's the yaml:

```
    # Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger: none

variables:

  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'redacted'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'redacted'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'redacted'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)

    steps:
    - task: NodeTool@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '14.x'
      displayName: 'Install Node.js'

    - script: |
        npm i -g -force @angular/cli@15.2
        npm i -force
        ng build --prod
      displayName: 'npm install etc'

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: 'Archive files'
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        includeRootFolder: false
        archiveType: zip
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
        replaceExistingArchive: true

    - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
      artifact: drop

- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: $(environmentName)
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure Web App Deploy: Redacted'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
              appType: webAppLinux
              appName: $(webAppName)
              runtimeStack: 'NODE|14.x'
              package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              startUpCommand: 'npm start'
```

Cheers,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.